# jQuery の scroll イベントが何回も繰り返される

Tags: javascript, jquery

お世話になっております。
表題の件ですが、ウェブサイトにてページトップボタンがフッター位置まで来た時にslideUpで消えるようにしたいのですが、何回も消えたり現れたりを繰り返してしまいます。

最初の記述に、スクロールを始めた時にslideを設定しているのが引っかかっておかしくなっているのかなと思うのですが、直し方がわかりません。

当方javascript全くの初心者です。
何卒ご教授の方よろしくお願いいたします。

https://jsfiddle.net/aq8j1rLL/

```js
$(function() {

  var topBtn = $('.pagetop');

  // ページトップボタンを非表示にする
  topBtn.hide();

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      topBtn.slideDown();
    } else {
      topBtn.slideUp();
    }

    // フッターに到達したら非表示

    // ドキュメントの高さ
    scrollHeight = $(document).height();

    //　ウィンドウの高さ+スクロールした高さ→　現在のトップからの位置
    scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();

    // フッターの高さ
    footHeight = $("footer").innerHeight();

    // 現在の下から位置が、フッターの高さの位置にはいったら
    if (scrollHeight - scrollPosition <= footHeight) {

      //  ".pagetop"のpositionをabsoluteに変更し、フッターの高さの位置にする        
      topBtn.css({
        "position": "absolute", //フッターの
      });
      topBtn.slideUp();

    } else {
      topBtn.css({
        "position": "fixed",
      });
      topBtn.slideDown();
    }

  });

  // トップへスムーススクロール
  $('.pagetop a').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body article {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
}
#maincontent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
}
/*---- フッター ----*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
/*---- ページトップボタン ----*/

#pagetop-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.pagetop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.pagetop > a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 102px;
  background-color: #ffdd3f;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>

  <section id="maincontent"></section>

  <footer>
    <div id="pagetop-wrap">
      <p class="pagetop">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </footer>

</article>
```

Comment: [最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能な](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)コードを貼ると回答を得やすいです。つまりHTMLとCSSも貼った方がいいです。

Comment: ソースをみた感じheightとtopがごっちゃになっている気がします。heightはボックス(i.e. フッター)の縦幅で、topは基準点からボックスの上辺までの距離です。

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ などを使ってサンプルをかいてもらえると、回答がしやすいので助かります。質問に使わないときでも問題の切り分けがしやすくなるので便利ですよ。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9583993.html

Comment: oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9583993.html　削除しました

Answer (score 2):

※だいぶコードが長いので、今回の質問と関係なさそうなところや改行を削っています

ご質問のコードでスクロール位置とslide方向の関係を見てみると...

```
// ここでは this === window なので、$(window).scrollTop() と同じ
// スクロール位置がページ上端なら slideUp()、でなければ slideDown()
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
  topBtn.slideDown();
} else {
  topBtn.slideUp();
}

// (略)

// フッターが画面内に入るところまでスクロールしたら slideUp()
if (scrollHeight - scrollPosition <= footHeight) {
  topBtn.css({ "position": "absolute" });
  topBtn.slideUp();
} else {
  topBtn.css({ "position": "fixed" });
  topBtn.slideDown();
}
```

フッターが画面内に入るところまでスクロールした場合、**前半のifで `slideDown()` が実行されたのちに、後半のifで `slideUp()` が実行される**ことになります。これが原因で、出たり消えたりする動きになっています。

また scroll イベントはスクロール位置が変わるたびに頻繁に呼び出されます。その度にこの上下運動のアニメーションが予約されるので、スクロールを止めてもしばらく動き続けます。

試しに、アニメーションの待ち数を左上に表示するようにしてみました。これを実行して、スクロールすると待ち数がどう変化するか、見てみてください。

```js
$(function() {
  var topBtn = $('.pagetop');
  topBtn.hide();

  // アニメーションの待ち数を表示
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#counter').text("queue: " + topBtn.queue().length);
  }, 200);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      topBtn.slideDown();
    } else {
      topBtn.slideUp();
    }

    scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    footHeight = $("footer").innerHeight();

    if (scrollHeight - scrollPosition <= footHeight) {
      topBtn.css({ "position": "absolute" });
      topBtn.slideUp();
    } else {
      topBtn.css({ "position": "fixed" });
      topBtn.slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#counter { position: fixed; width: 10em; background: #ddf;}
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }
article { position: relative; height: auto; }
#maincontent { height: 800px; }
footer { width: 100%; height: 48px; background-color: black; position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
.pagetop { position: fixed; right: 20px; bottom: 20px; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.pagetop > a { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #ffdd3f; border-radius: 50px; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter"></div>
<article>
  <section id="maincontent"></section>
  <footer>
    <div id="pagetop-wrap">
      <!-- pだとマージンがついてややこしいのでdivに変更 -->
      <div class="pagetop">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</article>
```

解決策は `if($(this).scrollTop() > 0)` の方を消すことです。もしページ上端でも別の処理を実行したいなら、「ページ上端」「ページ下端」「それ以外」で分岐するなどして、**一回のscrollイベントで slideUp/Down を複数回呼ばない**ようにしましょう。

これで「何回も消えたり現れたり」ということはなくなります。

Comment: 丁寧なご教授ありがとうございます。

>一回のscrollイベントで slideUp/Down を複数回呼ばない
https://jsfiddle.net/aq8j1rLL/3/　←このようにただscrollイベントの記述を分割するだけではダメなのですか？

Comment: @husky より正確には、前のアニメーションが完了する前に呼び出すのは避けた方がよい、ということになります（予約されてしまうので）。というか、slideUpとslideDownを両方呼び出した場合どういう動きを期待されているのですか？

Comment: ページを読み込んだ後、スクロールをしたタイミングでslideして表示、scrollTopに戻るとslideして非表示。
フッターまで到達するとslideして非表示フッターから離れると非表示。

ただこれがしたいだけなんです。。
わかってなさすぎて話にならないですよね。

Comment: @husky やりたいことはわかりました。で、回答文でも書きましたが、あなたのコードではscrollDownが完了する前にslideUpを呼び出す場合があります。分割しても完了する前というのは変わらないでしょう。この時どういう動きになると思いますか？先に呼んだscrollDownがキャンセルされると思いますか？実際にはそうはならず、scrollDownが終わった後にscrollUpが実行されてしまいます。/ このコメントの内容がどこまでご理解いただけたかを確認してから、回答を加筆修正しようかと思います。

Comment: scrollTop() > 0と言う書き方のせいで、フッター領域に入ってもこれが効いていて完了できていないということですかね？

スクロールを始めてからフッター領域に入るまで表示という書き方ができれば回避できるのかと。。

Comment: 色々調べて、スクロールが0以上maxScroll以下という記述でなんとか思い描いた動きができるようになったのですが、ブラウザを更新するたび、ボタンがフッター部分でちゃんと消えてくれたり、消えずに止まってしまったり不安定な状態になってます。
https://jsfiddle.net/aq8j1rLL/6/
よろしければこのコードを精査していただけませんか？
ちなみにjsfiddleでは常にちゃんと動いています。

Comment: @husky お返事遅くなってしまいすみません。きれいに動いてますね。maxScrollが事前に計算したっきりなのでウィンドウのリサイズに追従できなさそうなのが気になりますが、不安定の原因はぱっとは思いつきませんでした。他の方にも見てもらえるように、改めて別質問として投稿してはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: そうしてみます！色々ありがとうございました！